# Auto scale image to fit the rest of device height

Tags: javascript, html, css

First here is an image of what I looking for:

[image]

I want to put a header at the top, a paragraph below the header, and an SVG image below the paragraph. I would like this to scale properly on any sized device (well 320x480 is the smallest I am going to go which is an iPhone4 sized device).

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;">
            <div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Some long paragraph will be inserted here</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="mySvg.svg" /> <!-- This image should scale to fit the remaining of the screen size. -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is on a small device there are scrollbars and you need to scroll down to view the rest of the image. I would like it to scale properly so that it fits perfectly into the screen so no scrolling is needed.

EDIT: I am using a framework and as a result of the framework I cannot edit the HTML or BODY tags

Comment: aspect ratio doesn't matter?

Comment: Hi, yes the aspect ratio of the svg image does matter. If the image is longer than wider the height should not go below the screen and if the image is wider than longer it should not get cut off by the left and right side of the screen.

Comment: if it does, just give it `style="width:100%;"` but height might not be as you expected

Comment: body{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width: 100%; that doesnt work?

Comment: @DanyCode no it does not. By the way, I am testing this using chrome tools and using device tools set to iPhone4 which gives a resolution of 320x480.

Comment: something like **[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/upb4t3nf/)**?

Comment: @ChrisM If the image is long there is still a vertical scrollbar. I need it to scale down in this situation.

Comment: what is the size of the image that you are working with

Comment: the svg image is 71 pixels wide and 95 pixels long

Comment: a scroll bar on the window or on the div?  do you have a fixed height on the containing div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the approach with flexbox + position tricks.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1u8vh65/)**

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.container div:last-child img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/w3c.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, use flexbox + background image with size contain.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ncat18m/)**

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  background: url("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/w3c.svg") 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, but the question I asked is a simplified version of my actual real life use case. Is it possible to do something similar, but not touch the html or body tags as I am actually writing this code inside of an angular2 web framework where there is only really 1 page with many views? So If I modify the the head or body tag it will actually effect all my pages.

Comment: How about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y1h8q4oq/)? I added a class to the div and removed the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

i just gaved the body an min-height and min-width like that it never becommes more small than the phone

```css
.test{
  min-height:480px;
  min-width: 320px;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
 body{
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
 <body>
        <div class="test" style="height:100%;position:relative;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;">

            <div class="para">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Some long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted hereSome long paragraph will be inserted here</p>
            </div>

            <div class="test">
 
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/71/95" /> <!-- This image should scale to fit the remaining of the screen size. -->

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: The svg scales to 100 of the width causing the height to make a scrollbar.